# Send only text not number/icon using passing data with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

How I,m send only text not number/icon using passing data with intent.
Thank Before Guys.

Example i send string : Bali (1120).
i will receive only : Bali

Send data intent :

```
 Intent hotelLocation = new Intent(view.getContext(), HotelActivity.class);
 hotelLocation.putExtra("Location", tvHotelFind.getText().toString());
 hotelLocation.setType("text/plain");
 view.getContext().startActivity(hotelLocation);
```

Receive data Intent :

```
String titleresult = getIntent().getStringExtra("Location");
mHotelTujuan.setText(titleresult);
```

Comment: Add some code I still do not get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all number before send

```
String yourString = tvHotelFind.getText().toString(); 
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", ""); 
hotelLocation.putExtra("Location", yourString);
```

And then pass intent with yourString.

Comment: Hiii MeosCoder,,, i use like your code but not work. thanks

Comment: String yourString = tvHotelFind.getText().toString();
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
hotelLocation.putExtra("Location", yourString);

Comment: Thanks MeosCoder,,, it's work.
But how i'am send data : Bali, Indonesia (120 Hotel).
i receive only = Bali, Indonesia

Comment: Not receive `Hotel` ?